# Windows XP BSOD and Boot loop (Potential driver issue.)

Tags: windows, boot, windows-xp, windows-registry, bsod

I'm sorry if this seems like a duplicate question, but I've been stuck on this.

My WinXP machine has been experiencing a specific BSOD lately, with the STOP code;

0x0000007b (0xBACC3528, 0xC0000034, 0x00000000, 0x00000000).

I have tried [replacing the registry](https://neosmart.net/wiki/fix-registry/#Fix_a_corrupt_registry_in_Windows_XP), running a ClamWin and Malwarebytes scan on it; and replacing the drivers with a donor installation.

All of that is futile, however, so I enabled boot logging and need help finding out what exactly is the problem [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/N2wW50ZB).

(I read that the boot log doesn't necessarily point to what went wrong, so I don't know if it'll help or not.)

Safe mode also doesn't work.

Comment: try to boot in safe mode, and then inspect system log via Windows Log Viewer

Comment: @Rafael Sorry I forgot to mention this, but safe mode does not work. Sorry.

Comment: Is System Restore turned on? If yes, try to boot to safe mode, but don't select Safe Mode, and select System Restore. Then select a date, when your computer worked properly. It may help you.

Comment: How do you boot to safe mode without selecting safe mode?

Comment: When you boot to windows, hit F8 to get a possibility to enter to Safe Mode. But when you enter to safe mode, and System Restore is enabled, Windows lets you to choose. What exactly do you want to do: System Restore or Continue to safe mode?
In this case - select System Restore. A calendar will be displayed. And select a date, when your computer booted okay. And press Enter, wait and restart your computer. It should boot in normal mode then.

Comment: I unfortunately don't get a chance to do that, it restarts before I can get to that screen.

Comment: Then try to follow this instruction: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-xp-keep-restarting-itself/a90e5d4f-3367-4a6b-b6ca-ef8cdfeed2d3

Comment: See this page>>>>https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/troubleshoot-inaccessible-boot-device